# Firebase unique notification key for a device group

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a message to all the Android users of my app via a php website. I'm using the following code, but I have a problem.

I don't know to get the unique key for the `to:`. I want to send it to all android users of the app.

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H \
    "Authorization:key=<Your Api key>"  -X POST \
    -d '{"to": "<aUniqueKey>","data": {"hello": '\
    '"This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Device Group Message!"}}'
    https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

Comment: can I ask why php? if it something you preferred because it could be done a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The value needed for the `to` parameter is a [Registration Token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials) which is [generated in the Android App side](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register).

For your use-case, I would suggest using [Topic Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging). Subscribing each user to a specific topic automatically.